# Switching between data types

Tags: c, casting, type-conversion

I'm attempting to create a simple calculator in C. For the calculator, I'm trying to include an option to switch between using double precision variables and integers. By default the calculator is in double precision mode.

Is there a way to easily toggle my data types back and forth between int and double? Preferably through type casting?

For example, here's the addition part of switch statement (the first case):

```
    case 1:
      printf("Enter first term: ");
      scanf("%lf", &a);
      printf("Enter second term: ");
      scanf("%lf", &b);
      printf("The sum is: %.15lf\n", a + b);
      break;
```

The cases for subtracting, multiplying, and dividing follow the same format; respectively, cases 2, 3, and 4. Is there a way to apply a case (say add a case 5) to switch all double values to int?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to change the values, just output the result as an int:

```
printf("The sum is: %d\n", (int)(a + b));
```